# Javascript Koans - array reference

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have problem understand a section of the array references in Javascript koans:

```
it("should know array references", function () {
  var array = [ "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" ]; 
  var assignedArray = array;
  assignedArray[5] = "changed in assignedArray"; 
  expect(array[5]).toBe('changed in assignedArray');
```

in here, why does changing assignedArray[5] affects the array? Through my understanding,
 assignedArray would only reference to the array and change assigned array would not affect the array itself.

Comment: What's "Javascript koans"?

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I guess, it might be some js book

Comment: Arrays are objects, and values of object type are references to those objects. So `array` and `assignedArray` are two distinct values that are both references to the same thing. If you go through one of them and make a change to the object behind it, the change will be visible through the other. It's just like pointers in C.

Comment: on arrays of primitives, you can get a new copy using slice: var assignedArray = array.slice();

Comment: This post is similar to that one:

[So you may have your answer from this link]
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583013/javascript-koans-array-questions

Answer (score 0):

The value of a variable holding an object is a reference to that object. That is, there is an array in memory somewhere and both `array` and `assignedArray` refer to that same location. The statement `assignedArray = array` assigns the value of `array` -- a reference to the array -- to `assignedArray` so that they both refer to the same thing.